# VRP with multiple locations for the same customer?

Tags: optimization, integer-programming, discrete-optimization

I am looking into the vehicle routing problem, and am looking for a specific case where a vehicle can visit a costumer at multiple locations, the vehicle only have to visit one of the locations. Does such a problem exist already?

Comment: It has certainly been studied for one vehicle: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_TSP_problem.  You might have better luck here: https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vehicle-routing

Comment: @RobPratt thank you so much, I will try to look into the TSP and maybe I can extend it to my problem.